# MySql Query- Exclude duplicate records in count based on date

Tags: mysql

I have table called **post_likes** which contain the following fields

- id (int)
- post_id (int)
- type (enum) (FB_LIKES or LINKEDIN_LIKES)
- user_hash (varchar) (FB or Linkedin unique identifier)
- like_count (int)
- created_date (timestamp)

**Created_at** is based on UTC time zone.

Our business logic is that user can add **LIKE** one time per day (based on PST timezone) for the post. Meaning, 1 **LIKE** from FB and 1 **LIKE** from Linkedin.

I have a condition in application side to check and restrict peoples who are trying to give like same day. Somehow, some users added duplicate **LIKES** for the same day (it might be code or web server issue. Just leave this for now).

My current query is as follows to get the count of each post

```
SELECT `id`,  
       `title`,  
       Sum(IF(`type` = 'FB_LIKES', like_count, 0)) AS fb_like_counts, 
       Sum(IF(`type` = 'LINKEDIN_LIKES', like_count, 0)) AS linkedin_like_counts, 
       Sum(`like_count`) AS total_like_counts 
FROM   `post_likes` 
GROUP  BY `title`
ORDER  BY `total_like_counts` DESC;
```

Now, I want to get DISTINCT counts. because some of the post has duplicate likes for the same day. Here same user can like next day.

- So need to add a condition based on PST timezone  and exclude duplicate likes for the same day

**Note: Sorry for my bad english and thanks in advance**

Comment: Please include sample data and expected output in your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the late update. Below is my final query which gives the correct result

```
SELECT `id`, 
   `title`, 
   Sum(IF(`type` = 'FB_LIKES', like_count, 0))       AS fb_like_counts, 
   Sum(IF(`type` = 'LINKEDIN_LIKES', like_count, 0)) AS linkedin_like_counts, 
   Sum(`like_count`)                                 AS 
   total_like_counts  FROM   (SELECT *, 
           Date_format(Convert_tz(created_at, '+00:00', '-8:00'), '%Y-%m-%d' 
   ) AS date_pst 
    FROM   `post_likes` 
    GROUP  BY type, 
              title, 
              date_pst, 
              uid_hash) AS D1 
    GROUP  BY `title` 
    ORDER  BY `total_like_counts` DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

You just have to make a few adjustments to your query to select distinct date from your table. For the following solution I added a new select statement to return the same **post_likes** table but with distinct dates. This will allow me to run my query on a filtered set of **post_likes**

```
SELECT `id`,  
       `title`,
       `user_hash` as liked_user,
       Sum(IF(`type` = 'FB_LIKES', like_count, 0)) AS fb_like_counts, 
       Sum(IF(`type` = 'LINKEDIN_LIKES', like_count, 0)) AS linkedin_like_counts, 
       Sum(`like_count`) AS total_like_counts 
FROM   (SELECT * FROM post_likes GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(`created_date`, '%m %d %Y'), user_hash, type) AS post_likes
GROUP  BY `title`, DATE_FORMAT(`created_date`, '%m %d %Y'), user_hash
ORDER  BY `total_like_counts` DESC;
```

**You can use the following query to recreate the schema**

```
CREATE TABLE `post_likes` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `post_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `type` enum('FB_LIKES','LINKEDIN_LIKES') NOT NULL,
  `user_hash` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `like_count` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created_date` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);

insert into post_likes VALUES (
  1, 'A', 1, 'FB_LIKES', 'ABC', 1, '2018-06-25 05:49:41'
);

insert into post_likes VALUES (
2, 'A', 1, 'FB_LIKES', 'DEF', 1, '2018-06-25 05:50:01'
);

insert into post_likes VALUES (
3, 'A', 1, 'LINKEDIN_LIKES', 'ABC', 1, '2018-06-25 05:50:16'
);

insert into post_likes VALUES (
4, 'A', 1, 'LINKEDIN_LIKES', 'DEF', 1, '2018-06-25 05:50:23'
);

insert into post_likes VALUES (
5,'A', 1, 'LINKEDIN_LIKES', 'ABC', 1, '2018-06-25 05:50:16'
);

insert into post_likes VALUES (
6, 'A', 1, 'FB_LIKES', 'DEF', 1, '2018-06-25 05:50:01'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say below is the probable table structure

```
CREATE TABLE `post_likes` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `post_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `type` enum('FB_LIKES','LINKEDIN_LIKES') NOT NULL,
  `user_hash` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `like_count` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created_date` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Below is the sample data:

```
INSERT INTO `post_likes` (`id`, `title`, `post_id`, `type`, `user_hash`, `like_count`, `created_date`) VALUES
(1, 'A', 1, 'FB_LIKES', 'ABC', 1, '2018-06-25 05:49:41'),
(2, 'A', 1, 'FB_LIKES', 'DEF', 1, '2018-06-25 05:50:01'),
(3, 'A', 1, 'LINKEDIN_LIKES', 'ABC', 1, '2018-06-25 05:50:16'),
(4, 'A', 1, 'LINKEDIN_LIKES', 'DEF', 1, '2018-06-25 05:50:23'),
(5, 'A', 1, 'FB_LIKES', 'ABC', 1, '2018-06-26 05:50:38');
```

Here comes the query with date field to have unique records day-wise considering you don't have any duplicate records present in table:

```
SELECT `id`, `title`, Sum(IF(`type` = 'FB_LIKES', like_count, 0)) AS fb_like_counts, Sum(IF(`type` = 'LINKEDIN_LIKES', like_count, 0)) AS linkedin_like_counts, Sum(`like_count`) AS total_like_counts, DATE_FORMAT(`created_date`, '%Y-%m-%d') AS `liked_date` 
FROM `post_likes` 
GROUP BY `title`, `liked_date`
ORDER BY `total_like_counts` DESC;
```